# WP display content based on content id

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I am trying to display content based on if the category id matches the array. So far this code displays nothing. Unsure as to what I have coded wrong. Any help would be great.

```
    <header class="">
  <div class=""> <a title="<?=$post->post_title?>" href="<?=esc_url( get_permalink() )?>" rel="bookmark">
    <div onClick="">
      <?php $showmapsortfor = array(2,3);
  if(in_array($_category->getId(),$showmapsortfor )):?>
      <?
if ( is_single() ) :
the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
else :
the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
endif;
?>
      <div>
        <div id="1">A </div>
        <div id="2">B </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  </a>
  </div>
  <?php else: ?>
  <?
if ( is_single() ) :
the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
else :
the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
endif;
?>
  <div>
    <div id="1">C </div>
    <div id="2">D </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  </div>
  </a>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing allot of looking around and trial and error I found the answer I was looking for.

```
<div class=""> <a title="<?=$post->post_title?>" href="<?=esc_url( get_permalink() )?>" rel="bookmark">
    <div onClick="">

    <?php if ( is_category( array(2,3) ) ) {?>

      <div>
        <div id="1">A </div>
        <div id="2">B </div>
      </div>

  </div>
  </a>
  </div>

<?php } else { ?>

<div>
    <div id="1">C </div>
    <div id="2">D </div>
  </div>

  </div>
  </a>
  </div>
<? } ?>
```